# Which site: Using revision control (specifically Subversion)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site should I post the question, "How can I modify my Subversion repository to do *xyz*?"

- Stack Overflow: "software tools commonly used by programmers"
- Super User: about "computer software"
- Programmers: "software configuration management"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source control is firmly within the realm of "software tools used by programmers," so Stack Overflow is a great home for it.  There's even a tag for [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) with some 23 thousand questions.  As long it doesn't fail other off-topic reasons (like too broad, primarily opinion based, unclear) and isn't a duplicate feel free to ask it here.  Because of how many question have already been asked about it, try to find the solution first to avoid asking a duplicate question.